# How to grab specific sections of HTML from web request(windows phone)

Tags: html, xpath, windows-phone

I'm trying to make an app for windows phone that uses a web request to grab a page, output the full webpage to a variable and grab certain points of data from the page.

My issue is that the data which I want to grab does not have an id anywhere in it, So the only method i can think of is xpath, but I don't know how to implement this on windows phone.

I've tried **htmlagilitypack** and couldn't find a solution in there. I've attached a sample of the data I'd be grabbing from the table:

```
<td align="RIGHT" valign="TOP">
<font size="3" face="ARIAL,SANS-SERIF" color="#000000">37.13
</font>
</td>
```

I want to grab just the **37.13**.

Any help would really be appreciated, as I have NO clue how to proceed from this part.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by taking a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/804660/How-to-Parse-HTML-using-Csharp

It explains how to use xPath on WP.

Good luck!